# Is there a way to get the current color of the cursor?

Tags: emacs

Is there way to get the current color of the cursor in Emacs?

I could only find

```
(set-cursor-color "white")
```

But no "get-cursor-color".

It also does not appear to be a face:

```
(face-attribute 'cursor :foreground)
; => undefined
```

I have the idea that it is a "higher" level binding (as it is also possible to set it as an argument to executing Emacs).

But I would still like to temporarily change the cursor color; only if I know how to change it back.

Given a user might change the theme in the meantime, it has to be the real "current" cursor color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's indeed a face. However, not a `foreground` but a `background`, i.e,

```
(face-attribute 'cursor :background)
; => "black"
```

Answer (score 3):

The cursor color can be different for different frames.  To check it for a given frame, you can check frame parameter `cursor-color`.  It is equivalent to the `:background` attribute of face `cursor`.

For the selected frame:

```
(frame-parameter nil 'cursor-color)
```

For any frame `FRAME`:

```
(frame-parameter FRAME 'cursor-color)
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Font and Color Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-and-Color-Parameters.html).